# Android spinner not getting the desire result

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am trying spinner from  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvYGM.png):http://www.ahotbrew.com/android-dropdown-spinner-example/.

The code is working but the result is not that I want. The result is this:

[image: I got this]

But I want the spinner like below:

[image: But I want this]

Don't forget to see the attachment.

Min sdk 15, compile sdk 23.

Comment: Please provide the relevant code you have written.

Comment: You get that look because of the app compat material look. You should try and follow the material design guidelines. If you insist of having your own look-and-feel read this https://guides.codepath.com/android/Developing-Custom-Themes

Comment: Exactly what is wrong with the result. Is it that you don't like Caffe Americano as opposed to Cappucino? It is the size? Is it the lines separating the items? Is it something else?

Comment: What attachment should we not forget to see?

Comment: @MikeT i want the line and triangle icon "cappuccuno" the second one but i got the first one as i told you

Comment: @halfer i want the line and triangle icon "cappuccuno" the second one but i got the first one as i told you

Comment: @TudorLuca i am getting the same problem spinner is like the first picture

Comment: Have you created a custom theme for your spinner with the looks you wanted?

Comment: Yes my problem is solved by your answer the issues is solved my setting theme "android.Theme.Holo".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved by using custom theme for spinner in styles.xml:

Main.xml:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spThemes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/theme_array"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    style="@style/spinner_style"
    />
```

Styles.xml:

```
 <style name="spinner_style" >
    <item name="android:theme">@android:style/Theme.Holo</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>

    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```